# How to create a file with cat command and content, inside a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, cat

I want to create a shell script which executes the below content one after the another?

below are few commands of my scripts which contains a file creation with cat command, how to add these commands inside a shell script sequentially to execute one after the other,

```
apt-get install -y docker.io

cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
> {
> "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
> }
> EOF

apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm Kubectl
```

Comment: You just put the commands in your script and they'll execute sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use cat and not echo it straight to the file?

```
#!/bash/bin

apt-get install -y docker.io

echo "\n{\n\"exec-opts\": [\"native.cgroupdriver=systemd\"]\n}" >> /etc/docker/daemon.json 

apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm Kubectl
```

Comment: Because the way `echo` deals with `\n` is a bit of a lottery?